# d3 bars needs to move from bottom to up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a d3 bar graph.

1. I am trying to animate bars grow from bottom to upwards. how to achieve it?
2. also, how to make labels ie text of bars stay at the top of the bars and move along with them?

currently, bars are starting at top and going down to zero.

```js
        d3.select("body")
          .append("h2")
          .text("BAR GRAPH");

        const dataset = [12, 31, 22, 17, 25, 18, 29, 14, 9];

        const w = 500;
        const h = 120;

        const svg = d3
          .select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h);

        var bars = svg
          .selectAll("rect")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
          .attr("y", (d, i) => h - 3 * d)
          .attr("width", 25)
          .attr("height", (d, i) => 3 * d)
          .attr("fill", "navy");

        bars
          .transition()
          .duration(400)
          .attr("y", h)
          .attr("height", (d, i) => 3 * d);

        svg
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .text(d => d)
          .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
          .attr("y", (d, i) => h - 3 * d - 3)
          .style("font-size", "25px")
          .style("fill", "red")
          .append("title")
          .text(d => d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was almost on point for the bars, you just need to change the order of the affectation to the y attribute of bars and set the height attribute of bars to 0 at the start.

I just modified the three lines in your example and marked them with comments to show what to change to achieve your desired effect.

To make the labels follow the bars you can just add a transition on them with the same duration ! I added some lines in the last block and modified one to achieve the effect.

Hope it helps :)

```js
d3.select("body")
          .append("h2")
          .text("BAR GRAPH");

        const dataset = [12, 31, 22, 17, 25, 18, 29, 14, 9];

        const w = 500;
        const h = 120;

        const svg = d3
          .select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h);

        var bars = svg
          .selectAll("rect")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
          .attr("y", h) // modified here
          .attr("width", 25)
          .attr("height", 0) // modified here
          .attr("fill", "navy");

        bars
          .transition()
          .duration(400)
          .attr("y", (d, i) => h - 3 * d) // modified here
          .attr("height", (d, i) => 3 * d);

        // modified a bit here
        var labels = svg
          .selectAll("text")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .text(d => d)
          .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
          .attr("y", h) // modified here
          .style("font-size", "25px")
          .style("fill", "red");
       
        labels
          .append("title")
          .text(d => d);
        
        labels
          .transition() // added here
          .duration(400) // added here
          .attr("y", (d, i) => h - 3 * d - 3) // added here
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```